# Combining observables conditionally

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have two observables, one `IObservable<AlertData>` and the other `IObservable<SoundRequestData>`. `AlertData` contains a property `Id`, which knows which `SoundRequestData` belongs to it. `SoundRequestData` only knows about itself and has an `Id` property which can be matched to the one in `AlertData`.

I want to combine these two data types into a new type `AlertDataViewModel`. However, I cannot be sure that the order of the data that arrives in both observables are the same. I do not care about the order in the output either right now.

What I want is to match `AlertData` with `SoundRequestData`.

The way I am doing it now, which works but is slow, is to wait until one of the observables is done fetching all the data into a `ObservableCollection`. Afterwards I start the other observable and match up the Id's.

Is there a better way of doing this? I guess this could be expressed as the following marble diagram:

[image: Imgur]

So `a.id=1` matches up to `3.id=1`, `b.id=2` matches up to `4.id=2` and so forth.

Comment: Why not wait until both observables are done?

Comment: There is a lot of data, so it takes a while to fetch it all. Hence, I want to be able to present the data as quickly as possible to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's introduce a little extension method for `IObserver<T>`.

```
public static IObserver<T> Safe<T>(this IObserver<T> observer)
{
    var done = false;
    return Observer.Create<TResult>(
        value =>
        {
            if (!done)
            {
                observer.OnNext(value);
            }
        },
        error =>
        {
            if (!done)
            {
                done = true;
                observer.OnError(error);
            }
        },
        () =>
        {
            if (!done)
            {
                done = true;
                observer.OnCompleted();
            }
        });
}
```

This just ensures that the observer is called in the pattern `OnNext*(OnError|OnCompleted)` and that violations of that are just ignored.

We can now implement the operator you have described by buffering values from both sequences by key and only emitting them when we have a key match between the two sequences.

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Join<T1, T2, TKey, TResult>(
    IObservable<T1> source1,
    IObservable<T2> source2,
    Func<T1, TKey> key1,
    Func<T2, TKey> key2,
    Func<T1, T2, TResult> selector)
{
    return Observable.Create<TResult>(observer =>
    {
        var dict1 = new Dictionary<TKey, T1>();
        var dict2 = new Dictionary<TKey, T2>();
        var gate = new object();
        var safeObserver = observer.Safe();
        Action<TKey> emit = k =>
        {
            T1 value1;
            T2 value2;
            if (dict1.TryGetValue(k, out value1) && dict2.TryGetValue(k, out value2))
            {
                var result = selector(value1, value2);
                safeObserver.OnValue(result);
                dict1.Remove(k);
                dict2.Remove(k);
            }
        };
        return new CompositeDisposable(
            source1.Synchronize(gate).Subscribe(
                value1 =>
                {
                    var k = key1(value1);
                    dict1[k] = value1;
                    emit(k);
                },
                safeObserver.OnError,
                safeObserver.OnCompleted),
            source2.Synchronize(gate).Subscribe(
                value2 =>
                {
                    var k = key2(value2);
                    dict2[k] = value2;
                    emit(k);
                },
                safeObserver.OnError,
                safeObserver.OnCompleted));
    });
}
```

Example:

```
IObservable<AlertData> alertDatas = ...;
IObservable<SoundRequestData> = soundRequestDatas = ...;
IObservable<AlertDataViewModel> alertDataViewModels = Join(
    alertDatas,
    soundRequestDatas,
    alertData => alertData.Id,
    soundRequestData => soundRequestData.Id,
    (alertData, soundRequestData) => new AlertDataViewModel
    {
        AlertData = alertData,
        SoundRequestData = soundRequestData
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the prettiest, but it will work.

It will return this class, which is just a collection of the original two:

```
class Aggregate
{
    public AlertData AlertData {get;set;}
    public SoundRequestData SoundRequestData { get; set; }
    public int Id { get { return AlertData == null ? SoundRequestData.Id : AlertData.Id; } } 
}
```

This is the joining logic:

```
var joined = Observable.Merge(   // Convert the two sources into half-filled aggregates and merge them
        source1.Select(a => new Aggregate() { AlertData = a }),
        source2.Select(s => new Aggregate() { SoundRequestData = s }))
    .GroupBy(a => a.Id)
    // We only need two for each Id
    .Select(group => group.Take(2))  
    // This looks ugly, but is just joining the two messages into one
    .Select(group => group.Aggregate(new Aggregate(), (agg, newData) => new Aggregate() { AlertData = agg.AlertData ?? newData.AlertData, SoundRequestData = agg.SoundRequestData ?? newData.SoundRequestData }))
    // Back to one stream
    .Merge();
```